# How to find unused Gradle repositories

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a project that has added and removed library dependencies over time, and more than one repository is being used. Is there a way to see which of the declared repositories are or aren't being used?

Comment: Clear gradle's cache, comment the repositories out and uncomment it till the whole project builds successfully. That's the only idea that comes to my head :/

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to clean caches as they are repository aware (i.e. if you don't declare the repository(s) that the cached dependency was sourced from, you won't get the cached artifact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to see which of the declared repositories are (not) being used. Perhaps you could get this information by running with `--refresh-dependencies` and scraping the `--info` logs. Otherwise it will likely be a manual trial-and-error operation (comment repositories in/out until you've found a minimal set).

Comment: Thanks, I had been using the trial-and-error and was wondering if I missed something. The combined --refresh-dependencies and --info options seem useful.